# Update a sub-sub array, mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My document in collection list:

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b144363d7"),
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-21T07:51:39.987Z"),
        "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-21T07:51:39.987Z"),
        "title" : "List",
        "mainCats" : [ 
            {
                "mainCatId" : "1",
                "title" : "Cars",
                "_id" : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b1443650d"),
                "subs" : [ 
                    {
                        "subId" : "1.1",
                        "title" : "Tires",
                        "_id" : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b1443653c"),
                    }
               ]
         }
      ]
}
```

The title ("Tires") in subs array should be updated by the subId (1.1) as criteria.

Something like:

```
db.list.update(
    {
        '_id' : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b144363d7"),
        'mainCats.subs.subId' : '1.1'
    },

    {
        $set : {
            'mainCats.subs.title' : 'New title',
        }
    }
)
```

Cant get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

Well perhaps this is late but since I found this answer on SO, but I found this [operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) did the trick for me.

```
db.list.update(
    { '_id' : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b144363d7") },
    { $set: {"mainCats.$[].subs.$[category].title: 'New title' },
    { arrayFilters: [ {"category.subId": "1.1"} ]
)
```

The documentation should be a bit more helpful than what I might be able to do, but is just to help other people which reaches this post aswell.

In any case, the only obvious difference is that the condition corresponding to the subArray is now under the arrayFilters condition. And there you can see that instead of using the actual name of the property, we use the identifier we gave above.

The second difference is the $[] operator. This operator according to [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/)

> The all positional operator $[] indicates that the update operator should modify all elements in the specified array field.

And the only difference between that and $[category] is that we give an identifier for each of those elements so we can easily identify them.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You have to use [positional operator $](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/). But unfortunately  this operator cannot be applied twice, so you cannot traverse sub array. And it stands for the **first match** of the update query so you cannot use it for multiple update. 
If updating one sub document is all you need(as far as I can see in your query, you have id of sub document) you can achive your goal by redefining your data structure like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b144363d7"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-21T07:51:39.987Z"),
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-08-21T07:51:39.987Z"),
    "title" : "List",
    "categories": [
        {
            "mainCatId" : "1",
            "MainTitle" : "Cars",
            "subId" : "1.1",
            "subTitle" : "Tires"
        }
    ]
}
```

And so you can update one document(first matching the query) like below:

```
db.test.update(
{'_id' : ObjectId("599a910be15dad0b144363d7"), 'categories.subId': '1.1'},
{
    $set : {
        'categories.$.subTitle' : 'New title'
    }
}
)
```

Comment: It will work if you have arra of subdocuments. But if you have one array of subdocuments and into them another array of subdocument this method doesn't work. parents.$.childs.$.name = 'new name'